# Redux Sharing action between reducers vs triggering multiple actions

Tags: javascript, redux, flux

For example, if I have a login reducer and a user icon reducer. When I login, I want to update the user icon as well as storing the user's info. I am stuck between two choices:

First one is to export the USER_LOGIN action and have both login reducer and user icon reducer handle USER_LOGIN action.

Second approach is to have a 1 to 1 mapping between action and reducer (one type of action belongs to only one reducer). We have login reducer handle USER_LOGIN,  then with Saga/Thunk we dispatch a side effect UPDATE_USER_ICON to the user icon reducer.

Which one is a better practice ? I personally favor the second approach.

Comment: Let's not forget courtesy of adding a comment while downgrading any answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [Redux FAQ entry on dispatching multiple actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Actions.html#actions-multiple-actions):

> There's no specific rule for how you should structure your actions. Using an async middleware like Redux Thunk certainly enables scenarios such as dispatching multiple distinct but related actions in a row, dispatching actions to represent progression of an AJAX request, dispatching actions conditionally based on state, or even dispatching an action and checking the updated state immediately afterwards.
>
> In general, ask if these actions are related but independent, or should actually be represented as one action. Do what makes sense for your own situation but try to balance the readability of reducers with readability of the action log. For example, an action that includes the whole new state tree would make your reducer a one-liner, but the downside is now you have no history of why the changes are happening, so debugging gets really difficult. On the other hand, if you emit actions in a loop to keep them granular, it's a sign that you might want to introduce a new action type that is handled in a different way.
>
> Try to avoid dispatching several times synchronously in a row in the places where you're concerned about performance. There are a number of addons and approaches that can batch up dispatches as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would say your first approach is better and that is the one I use commonly. Yes it may affect readability of your code when you multiple reducers are acting upon same action type but it helps keep code less verbose (which is my major complain with React ecosystem) and a bit of performance. Actions like login would not have huge impact on performance but when I am making API calls on user actions, I just handle same action type in multiple reducers. For readability, I add comments and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to store the user icon in Redux? A better approach in this case is to have a selector that returns the icon based on the logged in user. That way you can keep the minimal amount of state in the store.

You can use the [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) library to cache selectors.